# Is a Swift Protocol equal to "extend" in typescript?

Tags: swift, typescript

I'm learning Swift at the moment and came across "protocols". They seem to me like a prebuild class that you extend, like in typescript, is that true?
Thanks, Pascal

Comment: You should not learn languages like this. There are rarely any "equal" things across programming languages. This is especially true for Swift and TypeScript, as one is nominally typed, and the other is structurally typed. Just learn Swift concepts for what they are.

Comment: Yeah, I agree to this. But I didn't understand the concept behind it at all, so I thought comparing it to TypeScript would be a great idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would compare them to `interface` in typescript.

```
interface FooBar {
  foo: () => void
  bar: () => void
}

class MyFooBar implements FooBar {

   public foo(): void {
      ...
   }

   public bar(): void {
      ...
   }
   
}
```